# Inspiron 15-3552 - Dell's Recovery Mechanism and Partition Sizing for 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, dell, data-recovery, inspiron

My new Dell Inspiron 15-3552 laptop came with 14.04.5 pre-installed by Dell.  A global software update attempt trashed its OS. Tests with a clone of its HDD show that there's a recovery mechanism that can be invoked to restore the OS "to factory state". I'll try another global software update (using Software Updater) later, meantime a couple of questions:

1. Is the recovery mechanism an OEM/proprietary feature or is it
   built-in to the 14.04 OS as standard? (During it the open window is
   titled "Dell Recovery" - and I didn't use any rescue media.)
2. I've shown Dell's HDD partitioning below. Is 3GB big enough for the
   OS? (I'd read it should be 7-10GB, someone else suggested 20-25GB
   was more like it for `/` (root) "if separate `/home`" - isn't `/home`
   always separate with Ubuntu?)

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk 
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
   sda      8:0    0  465.8G  0 disk 
   ├─sda1   8:1    0    500M  0 part 
   ├─sda2   8:2    0      3G  0 part 
   ├─sda3   8:3    0  454.5G  0 part 
   └─sda4   8:4    0    7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably assumed, "Dell Recovery" is Dell's proprietary backup and recovery software, it is not a part of Ubuntu.

Assuming Dell didn't pre-load your OS with a bunch of their own software, 3 GB should be enough for an original fresh(ish) installation of Ubuntu. If you're referring to the recovery partition, keep in mind it's also in a compressed format. For Dell computers that come with Windows OS, my experience is roughly in line with your research (7-10 GB recovery partition).

Comment: Thankfully there wasn't any bloatware pre-loaded by Dell.  As far as I can tell, the 3GB sda2 partition holds the installed OS, which partition Mike McGrath's Linux in Easy Steps (5th edition, p19) says you should make 7-10GB (if installing the OS yourself).  Did your "in a compressed state" refer to the installed OS or the files it's (re-)installed from?  Would those files be in the 500MB sda1 partition, do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if you were referring to the partition for the main OS or the recovery partition which holds the factory default image. The factory default image is in a compressed format and should easily fit in a partition less than 10GB for Ubuntu. When installing the main OS though, you generally want that to be a decently large enough partition to hold the OS and any packages/files you download or create. I'm not too sure what the 500 MB sda1 partition would be used for, my guess is just for storing kernel and ramdisk images.

Comment: So do you think that the main OS is in that 3GB sda2 partition and, if so, is that a big enough partition?  If it's not there, where is it?  (When I physically removed the HDD and connected it to my Windows 7 laptop, to clone it for tests, Windows Disk Management identified this partition as an OS.)